# Retrieve embedded youtube video ID with regex java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use regex in order to retrieve youtube video ID (embedded)

Assuming the following urls:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ/
http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ//
http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ?param
```

I'd like to get the ID "f0Cn2g8ekMQ".

I was trying to do it this way:

```
regex: https?://www\.youtube\.com/embed/(\S+)[/|\?]?.*
```

But it seems like the or operator doesn't work for me and the ID I recieve include the "/" or "?" and the rest of the string.

Is there any good way to do it with regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. Note the escaped `/` (slashes)

`/https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/([^\/?]+)/g`

https://regex101.com/r/57JeRU/1

For details, also check the code generator for JAVA.

Comment: Thanks. But ask far as I know you don't have to escape slashes, am I right?

Comment: Depends on the programming language or tool you are using. As I stated: check the code generator for details on the proper way to do this in JAVA code.

Comment: It works with java parser with or without escaping them.

Comment: Thanks. but shouldn't the question mark be escaped too?

Comment: @idogo this is not needed for `?` (and `.` (dot)) within a `[]` character class

Answer (score 0):

If you are very sure that the structure of the url is alway following the example you are using the you can use this:

```
    try{
        String add1 = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ/";
        String add2 = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ//";
        String add3 = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ?param";

        String []all1 = add1.replace("//", "/").split("[/?]");
        String []all2 = add2.replace("//", "/").split("[/?]");
        String []all3 = add3.replace("//", "/").split("[/?]");

        System.out.println(all1[3]);
        System.out.println(all2[3]);
        System.out.println(all3[3]);
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("URL format changed");
        //Do other things here if url structure changes
    }
```

***Output***

```
f0Cn2g8ekMQ
f0Cn2g8ekMQ
f0Cn2g8ekMQ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex `\/embed\/(\w+)[\/?]` not you can get the result like so :

```
String[] str = {"http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ/",
    "http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ//",
    "http://www.youtube.com/embed/f0Cn2g8ekMQ?param"};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\/embed\\/(\\w+)[\\/?]");
Matcher m;
for (String s : str) {
    m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
f0Cn2g8ekMQ
f0Cn2g8ekMQ
f0Cn2g8ekMQ
```

---

## Ideone demo